# system fields not invoking apex update trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, system-fields

I am trying to send an email to the contact owner when the email on contact has bounced. Below is the code, it works and send email to the contact if I remove the IsEmail Bounced condition.

```
trigger testTrigger on Contact(after update) {
    public Emailtemplate EmailBounced;
    EmailBounced = [select id, name from EmailTemplate where name = 'Email Bounce mail template'];
    for (Contact con: Trigger.New) {
        if (con.email != null && con.isemailBounced == TRUE) {
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            email.setTargetObjectId(con.ownerId);
            email.setsaveAsActivity(FALSE);
            email.setTemplateId(EmailBounced.id);
            email.setSubject('Email Bounced Alert : Email does not exist');
            if (con.ownerId != null) {
                Messaging.sendEmail(
                        new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
                system.debug('email sent ---------');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tried with the workflow but not luck.

Comment: Make sure that you have enable [bounce management](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_deliverability.htm&type=0) feature in your org. After that check your code. To verify update a contact with an invalid email address that you would know bounce email and verify your code.

Comment: the flag is turning TRUE, even though it is not invoking the trigger.

Comment: put a system.debug before the "if" statement where it is failing to check the values of bounce email field and also verify if the contact has email address.

Comment: you may be subject to this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_ignoring_operations.htm

Comment: how does `isemailBounced__c` get set?  this is a custom field. How is it related to OOB field `IsEmailBounced` ?

Comment: @cropredy It was my typing mistake here.. I have tried with the OOB field it self did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@sfdcfox covers this in an [2011 post in the Developer Forum](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009AwSIAU) that describes how bounces don't cause normal DML events on objects and hence triggers won't execute.

He suggests the following workaround (which makes sense as when a bounce occurs is asynchronous and hence when the notification occurs to the contact owner can be asynchronous as well)

- Write an Apex Scheduled Job (run daily)
- That queries for Contacts where `EmailBouncedDate = YESTERDAY`
- And then sets/updates a custom field on Contact such as `isReadyForBounceNotification__c` to true. This update will be a DML event ..
- That then is picked up by a workflow that sends out an email alert and finally resets the `isReadyForBounceNotification__c` to false.