# workflow rule/process builder not firing for field IsEmailBounced in Contact

Tags: process-builder, workflow, bounce-management

I trying to create follow-up tasks when a Contact email is bounced. There is a standard field in salesforce called [IsEmailBounced](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm) which I am using to determine whether or not I need to create a task, so if true then I create a task. The task is never created not using a workflow rule or a process builder. Have you ever successfully created a task via workflow rule/ process builder using the field [IsEmailBounced](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm)?

Comment: Have you enabled recursion on your process builder?

Comment: see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146309/system-fields-not-invoking-apex-update-trigger

Comment: @cropredy thanks a lot, your link helped me a lot.